# How to pre-select a table row at runtime?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I want to pre-select a table row in a splitView master controller as the view loads, Just like Apple does with the General selection in the Settings App in an Ipad.

I found some places suggesting using

```
let indexPathForSelection:NSIndexPath = tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: self, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone)
```

but the Xcode does not recognize the  scrollPosition code: `UITableViewScrollPositonNone` as a valid identifier

This should be a simple task but it seems no one is addressing it using Swift.

Comment: You cannot use `self` there, you need an actual indexPath. `let myIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)` then `indexPathForSelection:NSIndexPath = tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: myIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone)` should yield better results in placing the selection at the first row of the first section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code.

Your first mistake is, that you can't use the `selectRowAtIndexPath` method the way you do it. First you have to set the `NSIndexPath`. Like that:

```
var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: yourRow, inSection: yourSection)
```

Also you can't use `UITableViewScrollPositionNone` in Swift like you could in Objective-c. You have to use:

```
UITableViewScrollPosition.None
```

But I would recommend you use `Middle` in your case:

```
UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle
```

So to get the result you wanted, you should have to do something like this:

```
var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: yourRow, inSection: yourSection)
tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks to both of you for helping me on this. I'm new to IOS development and Swift and I'm having to translate some things from Objective-C to Swift. I hope it also helps someone else.

Comment: So where should this line of code placed?
    ' var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: yourRow, inSection: yourSection)
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle) '
shall it be inserted in viewDidLoad?